# Is there any solution to save the space when use the docx-mailmerage?

Tags: python, docx-mailmerge

I am using the Python docx-mailmerge library to create a docx.
But something is not like my hope.

My code:

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge

template='example.docx'
document_1 = MailMerge(template)
document_1.merge(misscount='>>> CSS Network Latencies\n    CRS-4678: Successful get misscount 30 for Cluster Synchronization Services.')
document_1.write('aaa.docx')
```

The ouptput in the docx is:

[image: image description here]

But my hope is:

[image: image description here]

I want the second line start with 4 space. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use '\t' after '\n' to tab the new line?

Comment: I already try it. But it doesn't work. The output is also like my first picture

Answer (score 0):

try using "\t" instead of 4 space. the effect is the same but this might work.
like so:

`'>>> CSS Network Latencies\n\tCRS-4678: Successful get misscount 30 for Cluster Synchronization Services.'`

Comment: I already try it. But it doesn't work. The output is also like my first picture.